# When computing contour integration with sines and cosines in the integrand, must we always first look at Euler's formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, residue-calculus, analyticity, singularity-theory

For example, in computing

$$\int_{Cr}\frac {\cos(z)}{(z^2+a^2)^2}dz$$

over a semi-circular contour, *must* I first look at

$$\int_{Cr}\frac {e^{iz}}{(z^2+a^2)^2}dz$$

compute this integral first, and then read off the real part of the answer?

What would be incorrect with just computing

$$\int_{Cr}\frac {\cos(z)}{(z^2+a^2)^2}dz$$

directly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no hard and fast rule that says you need to consider re-writing the integrand using Euler's formula. You can consider writing the integrand in any form you wish. The key is being able to find a form on the integrand in which the parts you don't care about go to zero on your given contour $C_r$.

So for your example here (I don't know because I haven't worked it out) if you just consider the integrand as is it might be the case that over one part of $C_r$ the integral actually diverges as you extend the radius of $C_r$ to infinity.

Where as if you re-write the integrand using Euler's formula you might find that the integral actually converges as you extend the radius to infinity.

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right.  In complex exponential form, on the upper semi-circle, I think the $e^{-iz}$ term of cosine would blow up.  On the lower semicircle, the other exponential term would blow up.  So we're pretty much stuck and can't give the estimates we'd want.  But looking *only* at $e^{iz}$ first, one of the two contours would be sufficient for computation.  Thanks so much for your response @okrzysik :-)

Comment: Hi @okrzysik, so is it correct to say that the complex sine and complex cosine are unbounded functions?  Thanks,

Comment: Ah, yes -- Liouville's theorem would easily confirm that, if I weren't convinced enough :-)  Thanks

Comment: @LebronJames glad I could be of help.